# How to define namespace in XML using DBMS_XMLDOM

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I am trying to generating below format xml using function:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OUTPUT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org">
 ....
```

Function:

```
FUNCTION f_get_details(
    p_employee_id NUMBER)
  RETURN XMLTYPE
IS
  v_xmltype xmltype;  
  --  
  main_node xmldom.DOMnode;
  ROOT_NODE XMLDOM.DOMNODE;  
  root_elmt xmldom.domelement;
  l_con_node dbms_xmldom.DOMnode;
  -- 
BEGIN
  l_domdoc := xmldom.newDomDocument; 
  --
  main_node := xmldom.makenode(l_domdoc);
  root_elmt := xmldom.createelement(l_domdoc, 'OUTPUT');
  --
  xmldom.setattribute(elem => root_elmt, name=> 'xmlns:xsi', newvalue=>'http://www.w3.org');
  --
  v_xmltype := dbms_xmldom.getXMLType(l_domdoc);
  dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(l_domdoc); 
  return v_xmltype;
END f_get_details;
```

function is generating xml in correct format but I am not able to mention namespace of output node. How I should fix it?
I have given namespace in this line of code:

```
 xmldom.setattribute(elem => root_elmt, name=> 'xmlns:xsi', newvalue=>'http://www.w3.org');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own unanswered question, as I have resolved this issue myself. Hope someone will find useful. Below function will add XML namespace now.

```
FUNCTION f_get_details(
    p_employee_id NUMBER)
  RETURN XMLTYPE
IS
  v_xmltype xmltype;  
  --  
  main_node xmldom.DOMnode;
  ROOT_NODE XMLDOM.DOMNODE;  
  r_elmt xmldom.domelement;
  l_con_node dbms_xmldom.DOMnode;
  -- 
BEGIN
 --Create an empty XML document
  l_domdoc := xmldom.newDomDocument; 
  --
 --XML declaration
  dbms_xmldom.setVersion(l_domdoc, '1.0" encoding="UTF-8');
  dbms_xmldom.setCharset(l_domdoc,'UTF-8');
 --set root node
  r_elmt := xmldom.createelement(l_domdoc, 'test');
  dbms_xmldom.setattribute(r_elmt,'xmlns:xsi','http://www.test.com');
  l_node := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(xmldom.makenode(l_domdoc), dbms_xmldom.makeNode(r_elmt));

  --
  v_xmltype := dbms_xmldom.getXMLType(l_domdoc);
  dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(l_domdoc); 
  /*
  * Rest of coding. 
  */
  return v_xmltype;
END f_get_details;
/
```